# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat7, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to make a webservice call in a program and deployed that in tomcat server. But I am getting the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider". But this class is available in weblogic.jar and the same is there in tomcat/lib folder. Any suggestion on how to solve this exception?

`EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [test] in context with path [/VTM-Engg-UI] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is`

`**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider] with root causejava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider**`

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:31)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:90)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:83)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at com.onstar.vcs.services.ws.ProcessVehicleTask.<init>(ProcessVehicleTask.java:42)
at com.onstar.vtm.manager.GetTaskWs.getTask(GetTaskWs.java:99)
at com.onstar.vtm.vehType.controller.VehTypeController.getGetTaskAttribute(VehTypeController.java:584)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be some possibilities.

The application can't access tomcat/lib/weblogic.jar file. May be it's not in application class path.

There might be more than one jar file that contains weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider and this could be posing a problem.

Check to see the complete class name with package name. Sometimes the version of the jar file might be an issue as well.

May be WLSProvider is not initialized properly. If you look at complete stack trace in your logs and see all the errors, there might be an error pointing to it's initialisation. Similar issue was posted long time back on JavaRanch - http://www.coderanch.com/t/582814/BEA-Weblogic/initialize-class-weblogic-wsee-jaxws

Dig deeper in your logs file and see if there are more errors. May be there is something else that needs to load before this class loads, and that might have not loaded properly.

Try paired programming. If you can get a peer looking at your problem, they might see something you might have missed. Many times two heads are better than one!

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Indu ! I am not sure what was the error. But I believe there were two different jar which has same class name. I was able to debug that error.